# Prisma Multiple relations to the same table

Tags: prisma

I want to be able to have a model that points to another.
Its a 1-to-1 relationship but of the same model.

For example, `MagazineYear` points to 4 different `Season` rows.

I keep getting the following error:

```
Error validating model "MagazineYear": Ambiguous relation detected. The fields `springSeasonIssue`, `summerSeasonIssue`, `fallSeasonIssue` and `winterSeasonIssue` in model `MagazineYear` both refer to `Season`. Please provide different relation names for them by adding `@relation(<name>).
```

```
model MagazineYear {
    id                String @id @default(cuid())
    springSeasonIssue Season
    summerSeasonIssue Season
    fallSeasonIssue   Season
    winterSeasonIssue Season
}

model Season {
    id         String     @id @default(cuid())
    seasonName seasonName
    theme      String
}

enum seasonName {
    SPRING
    SUMMER
    FALL
    WINTER
}
```

I've tried adding an `@relation(name: "xxxxxSeason")` for each of the season rows as follows:

```
model MagazineYear {
    id                  String @id @default(cuid())
    springSeasonIssueId String
    springSeasonIssue   Season @relation("magazineSpringSeason", fields: [springSeasonIssueId], references: [id])
    summerSeasonIssueId String
    summerSeasonIssue   Season @relation("magazineSummerSeason", fields: [summerSeasonIssueId], references: [id])
    fallSeasonIssueId   String
    fallSeasonIssue     Season @relation("magazineFallSeason", fields: [fallSeasonIssueId], references: [id])
    winterSeasonIssueId String
    winterSeasonIssue   Season @relation("magazineWinterSeason", fields: [winterSeasonIssueId], references: [id])
}

model Season {
    id                  String         @id @default(cuid())
    seasonName          seasonName
    theme               String
    magazineYearsSpring MagazineYear[] @relation("magazineSpringSeason")
    magazineYearsSummer MagazineYear[] @relation("magazineSummerSeason")
    magazineYearsFall   MagazineYear[] @relation("magazineFallSeason")
    magazineYearsWinter MagazineYear[] @relation("magazineWinterSeason")
}
```

But I don't see why the `Season` table would need to have four `MagazineYear[]` entries given that it will only be of one type.